# How to count number of row's with some values on different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need help. I need to count the rows that contain the same value that column A has in the second sheet. So I need to go through that column from the first sheet and count only those rows that have the same values as the column in the second sheet. How can I do that with vba code?

Comment: How much vba coding have you done so far? It's helpful to post some of the code you have already done, point out where you have a problem, and relate your question to that specific point. If you haven't coded anything yet, this isn't really the right place to ask. Instead, you should look at the many excel vba coding tutorials that are available free online and get some basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Sub Count_If_Equals()

    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim N_Of_Inputs As Integer
    Dim Bottom_Row_For_Comparing As Integer
    Dim DB_Bottom_Row_S1 As Integer
    Dim DB_Bottom_Row_S2 As Integer
    Dim DB_Start_Row As Byte
    Dim Pos As Integer
    Dim Name_Sheet1 As String
    Dim Name_Sheet2 As String
    Dim Col_To_Compare As Byte
    Dim Display_Result(1 To 2) As Byte
    
    'CONFIG
    DB_Start_Row = 5                 'in what row does the DB start?
    Col_To_Compare = 2            'in what column are the values to compare?
    Name_Sheet1 = "Sheet1"       'what is the name of the first sheet?
    Name_Sheet2 = "Sheet2"       'what is the name of the second sheet?
    Display_Result(1) = 3            'row to display result
    Display_Result(2) = 3            'column to display result
    
    'find bottom row of the DB in sheet 1
    DB_Bottom_Row_S1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name_Sheet1). _
    Cells(Rows.Count, Col_To_Compare).End(xlUp).Row
    'find bottom row of the DB in sheet 2
    DB_Bottom_Row_S2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Name_Sheet2). _
    Cells(Rows.Count, Col_To_Compare).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Bottom_Row_For_Comparing = WorksheetFunction.Min(DB_Bottom_Row_S1, DB_Bottom_Row_S2)
    
    'compare and count
    For Pos = DB_Start_Row To Bottom_Row_For_Comparing
    
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Pos, Col_To_Compare) = _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Pos, Col_To_Compare) Then
            
                    Count = Count + 1
            
            End If
    
    Next Pos
    
'display the result
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Display_Result(1), Display_Result(2)) = Count

End Sub
```